# Return message - no results from text box

Tags: jquery, textbox, messagebox

I'm very new to jquery and looking to learn.

I'm trying to develop a search page. At present nothing is returned if there is no match. I've tried various snippets to add add a message but it doesn't seem to work.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

```
 <input type="text" id="search-criteria"/><BR> 
 <input type="button" id="search" value="Policy Search"/><BR> 
 <div  class="contact-name" style='background-color:#f2f2f2'> Daniel </div> 
 <div class="contact-name" style='background-color:#f2f2f2'>david </div>



$('.contact-name').hide();
$('#search').click(function(){
$('.contact-name').hide();
var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
$('.contact-name').each(function(){
   if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
       $(this).show();
   }
});
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the HTML for the page, and the message you want to show.

Comment: Sorry I missed that! I've included it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the `.each` loop found a value; if it did, then exit early; if not, show the "no results" message.

```html
<!-- Add this element to the HTML. -->
<div class="no-results">There are no results available.</div>
```

```js
$(".contact-name, .no-results").hide();
$("#search").click(function() {
  $(".contact-name, .no-results").hide();
  var txt = $("#search-criteria").val();
  var found = false;
  $(".contact-name").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
      found = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (!found) {
    $('.no-results').show();
  }
});
```